# Degree of Precision Effect on Quadrature Accuracy

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

For an $n$ point Gaussian quadrature, one can show that it has degree of precision $2n - 1$ meaning it will exactly integrate polynomials of that degree or lower. Is it always true that a quadrature with a higher degree of precision will give better results for the integration of a non-polynomial function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to "is it always true" is always "no", especially in numerical methods. The issue is in how closely the integrand resembles a polynomial function. If the integrand is analytic in a large neighborhood of the interval of integration, then Gaussian quadrature converges extremely fast. But for integrals like $\int_{-1}^1\sqrt{1-x^4}\,dx$ or worse yet, $\int_{-1}^1 1/\sqrt{1-x^4}\,dx$, where the behavior is markedly non-polynomial, high degree of the method does not pay off. One is better off using a lower degree method on smaller subintervals. This is same story as with Legendre polynomial vs. polynomial splines.

For a technical treatment, see [Is Gauss Quadrature Better than Clenshaw-Curtis?](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/060659831) by Lloyd N. Trefethen.

> We compare the convergence behavior of Gauss quadrature with that of its younger brother, Clenshaw–Curtis. Seven-line MATLAB codes are presented that implement both methods, and experiments show that the supposed factor-of-$2$ advantage of Gauss quadrature is rarely realized.

For an example where Gaussian quadrature loses to the left endpoint rule, see [this post](http://calculus7.org/2014/06/01/unreasonable-effectiveness-of-the-left-endpoint-rule/).

Comment: Excellent links! If highly non-polynomial behaving functions are integrated better by a method with a lower degree of precision, would this imply that for some weird function one could actually do better than a given Gaussian quadrature by using a Gaussian quadrature with fewer points?

Comment: @SamManzer Sure, but my example will not be very insightful. Take any weird function on $[-1,1]$ such that $f(0)=\frac12 \int_{-1}^1 f$. Then the one-point quadrature method, which amounts to $2f(0)$, gives the precise result, while other methods will have some error.

Comment: So the rationalization for higher degrees of precision being better for lots of non-polynomial functions most of the time is something like the Weierstrass approximation theorem guaranteeing the existence of a very accurate polynomial approximation the integrand over the integration interval and if you have high enough degree of precision you will accurately integrate that (probably very high degree) polynomial?

Comment: @SamManzer The rationale for preferring one method over another is that it works better in practice. Theorems are nice to have in a book, but they are not what actually drives the choice of a method. Simpson's method does work better than trapezoidal most of the time, and 7-point Gaussian works better than Simpson most of the time. But the payoff for going much higher than that turns out to not justify the effort. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Kronrod_quadrature_formula) for an example of a practical choice of degree that is *actually used*.